# How to add a layer to a map, using the API

Tags: google-maps-engine

How do we associate a Layer with an existing map ? I looked in the API and there's nothing about this. So far, it seems to me that the only way to add a layer to a map would be to go through the web interface.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The [exp2](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/reference/exp2/#Layers) version of the GME API has this capability. Use layer/create to create a layer. I believe you can make a call to maps/create to add a layer to an existing map but I've not had a chance to try it myself yet.
layer/create is a rich function as you can apply many styling and filtering rules.

Once you've added the layer to the map you can process and publish the map also using the API.